# Ruby array to subarray with fall factor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any inbuilt method available to split large array into smaller chunks with dynamic fall factor?

Eg: `i=0
src_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`

if `batch_size = 5` and `fall_factor = 1`, first chunk should be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and subsequent array chunks should start from `start_index = i * (batch_size - fall_factor)`. ie, `start_index` will be `0, 4, 8, 12`, and

```
result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[13, 14]
```

if `fall_factor = 2` result should be as below

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I know how to SOLVE this. My question is if any inbuilt method available like `each_slice` to get this done instead of reinventing.

Comment: Could you give more examples/explanation of how the batch size and fall factor are expected to work?

Comment: @ndn: I hope you can get it now

Comment: @Downvoter, Could you explain?

Comment: All built-in methods are available either in [`Array` class](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html) or [`Enumerable` module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) - you can look up the documentation and ascertain for yourself whether any such method is available.

Comment: What is the `i = 0`? That makes no sense.

Comment: @sawa, 'i' is an iterator variable, will be incremented in each loop.

Comment: What is the `i = 0`? That makes no sense.

Comment: @sawa, see the previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

For example you can use just [`#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-step) method of `Numeric`

```
0.step(src_arr.size - fall_factor - 1, batch_size - fall_factor).map do |ind|
   src_arr[ind, batch_size]
end

# fall_factor = 1
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [13, 14]] 
# fall_factor = 2
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: This is the only correct, and an elegant solution. But perhaps, `[start, length]` construction is better than `[range]` here.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def doit(arr, batch_size, fall_factor)
  arr[batch_size..-1].
    each_slice(batch_size-fall_factor).
    each_with_object([arr[0,batch_size]]) { |b,c| c << [*c.last[-fall_factor..-1], *b] }
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = (1..14).to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 

doit(arr, 5, 1)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [13, 14]] 
doit(arr, 5, 2)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
doit(arr, 5, 3)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
  #    [9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13, 14]] 
doit(arr, 5, 4)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  #    [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
  #    [9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

**Explanation**

For `arr` above and:

```
batch_size = 5
fall_factor = 2
```

we have:

```
a = arr[batch_size..-1]
  #=> arr[5..-1]
  #=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] 
b = a.each_slice(batch_size-fall_factor)
  #=> a.each_slice(3) 
  #=> #<Enumerator: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]:each_slice(3)>
```

We can see the elements of the enumerator `b` by converting it to an array:

```
b.to_a
  #=> [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14]]
```

Continuing:

```
d = [arr[0,batch_size]]
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] 
b.each_with_object(d) { |b,c| c << [*c.last[-fall_factor..-1], *b] }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

To see how the last calculation is performed, let:

```
e = b.each_with_object(d)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]:
  #     each_slice(3)>:each_with_object([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])> 
e.to_a
  #=> [[[6, 7, 8], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]],
  #    [[9, 10, 11], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]],
  #    [[12, 13, 14], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]]
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to obtain each element of `e` that is passed to the block, set the block variables to each of those values and perform the block calculation. The first element is passed to the block:

```
b, c = e.next
  #=> [[6, 7, 8], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]] 
b #=> [6, 7, 8] 
c #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

The block calculation is therefore:

```
c << [*c.last[-fall_factor..-1], *b]
  #=> c << [*[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].last[-2..-1], *[6, 7, 8]]
  #   c << [*[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][-2..-1], *[6, 7, 8]]
  #   c << [*[4, 5], *[6, 7, 8]]
  #   c << [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The next element of `e` is now passed to the block:

```
b, c = e.next
  #=> [[9, 10, 11], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]] 
b #=> [9, 10, 11] 
c #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The remaining calculations are performed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on logic shared by you, below is one possible implementation:

```
b = 5  # batch size
f = 2  # fall factor

indices = (0...src_arr.size).collect {|i| i * (b-f)}.reject {|i| i + f >= src_arr.size}

result = indices.each_with_object([]) do |i, obj| 
    obj << src_arr[i, b]
end
p result
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: That is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for playing the role of [Referee](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/07/12/article-0-02B0114C0000044D-243_634x428.jpg)  :-)